# How do I get rid of these weird clumps in sculpts?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, sculpting, artifacts

Whenever I'm sculpting I notice these clumps of verts mostly on edges sharp or smooth. What do I do? (Also smoothing doesn't help)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe remesh and then smooth? you can remesh by clicking remesh is the right top corner in a sculpting window. the lower the voxel size the more resolution. so watch out that blender doesn't crash. and then hit remesh. hope that it works.

Comment: Yes, I have tried remesh + smooth but It is already pretty high poly count and still doesn't work. There are some areas that can be fixed with the scrape and fill brush but that doesn't work for everything like smooth faces.